# Where do I require sinatra settings?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, settings, require

I've got a sinatra project which consists of 3 sinatra apps (modular style).
I have my settings under `settings.rb`, I want to use those for all 3 sinatra apps.

I'm running `ruby 1.9.3p327`.

---

my `settings.rb`:

```
#Environments: :production, :development
set :environment, ENV['RACK_ENV'] ||= "development".to_sym

disable :run      #disable internal webserver

configure :development do
  set :haml           ,  :format => :html5, :ugly => false
  enable :static
  enable :show_exceptions
  enable :raise_errors
end

configure :production do
  set :haml           ,  :format => :html5, :ugly => true
  disable :static
  disable :show_exceptions
  disable :raise_errors
end
#######################
```

---

my `config.ru`:

```
require 'sinatra'       #Web Framework
require 'haml'          #Haml Rendering for the views
require './db_setup.rb' #DB Setup
require './models.rb'   #DB Models
require './app1.rb'     #app1
require './app2.rb'     #app2
require './app3.rb'     #app3

map '/' do
  run App1
end

map '/app2' do
  run App2
end

map '/app3' do
  run App3
end
```

---

Where do I place `require './settings.rb'`?

---

**Aviable places:**

in each app file at the top, eg `app1.rb`

in each app class with `Sinatra::Base` as parent

in `config.ru`

---

I don't know why but I, for me, none of them work. The only thing that actually works is copy and pasting the content of `settings.rb` in each app class. But this is really dirty, because I have to change 3 files if I need, eg, a different `<DOCTYPE>`

Comment: When you tried it in config.ru, did you put it before or after the appX requires?

Comment: it didn't work for all of them , just for the first one...I also tried to require ```settings.rb``` before every appX.rb ```require``` but it just uses the settings for the first app...

Comment: ok I made a mistake, it worked for none of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rewritten**

Ah, so the problem is not actually with require. What's happening is that `run` is creating new instances of the apps with default settings. The apps don't "inherit" the `configure` calls, which are just being set on the non-modular app; i.e you have to actually call `configure` from the context of the application.

I'd just do this with subclasses:

```
class BaseApp < Sinatra::Base
  set :environment, ENV['RACK_ENV'] ||= "development".to_sym
  #etc
end
```

And then have all the apps subclass from it, like

```
class App1 < BaseApp
   #your app
end
```

Comment: ok, it makes more sense that it works for none of them than for just one. the next thing to try is to put a `puts` statement at the end of settings.rb and confim it's actually executing when you require it

Comment: it only works if I put the content of `settings.rb` directly on the top of the class declaration...